# golang strange http error: read: connection reset by peer

Tags: http, go, curl, https

I need request a api, but golang program always return error: **connection reset by peer**, but use curl or python request always works normally.

On same machine:

## expected return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE SIMPLE_RETURN SYSTEM "https://qualysapi.qg2.apps.qualys.eu/api/2.0/simple_return.dtd">
<SIMPLE_RETURN>
  <RESPONSE>
    <DATETIME>2022-07-02T07:50:26Z</DATETIME>
    <CODE>2000</CODE>
    <TEXT>Bad Login/Password</TEXT>
  </RESPONSE>
</SIMPLE_RETURN>
```

## curl works:

```
curl -H "X-Requested-With:curl" -u "asdf:asdfdasf" "https://qualysguard.qg2.apps.qualys.eu/api/2.0/fo/asset/host/?action=list"
```

## python code works:

```
# test.py
import requests


url = 'https://qualysguard.qg2.apps.qualys.eu/api/2.0/fo/asset/host/?action=list'
res = requests.get(url,
                   headers={"X-Requested-With": "curl"},
                   auth=("asdf", "asdfas"))
print(res.text)
```

run it with python3 test.py

## golang code never works:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    url := "https://qualysguard.qg2.apps.qualys.eu/api/2.0/fo/asset/host/?action=list"

    client := http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        //Handle Error                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      panic(err)
    }

    req.Header.Set("X-Requested-With", "curl")
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Basic "+base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte("asdf:asdfas")))

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    sb := string(body)

    fmt.Println(sb)
}
```

I tried go version *1.18.3* and *1.10.8* and *1.17.2*, not works.

Comment: I tried this code and got the same error, but your code works to get another URL. It's possible that the web server which you're sending it to doesn't like Go's default user agent string, or something like that, which is unrelated to the programming language.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Suzu. After I set user agent to `curl` or anything except Go's default user agent(Go-http-client/1.1) , It works now.

Comment: I wonder what web server hates gophers :-)